# Wordpress calendar events/planner/scheduler

Tags: javascript, wordpress, events, calendar, schedule

I search plugin for calendar, who users can add events from calendar, like in this plugin: 
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_basic.shtml
easy select hours end add event

Regards! and please help

Answer (score 0):

If you're a JQuery guy, I would recommand to use *FullCalendar* plugin http://fullcalendar.io. I worked with it a year ago, it is flexible and gives you a high level of extensibility. And more importantly, its documentation is rich, so you can find the appropriate configuration options for any behavior you would like to implement http://fullcalendar.io/docs/.
It's released under MIT license so go ahead and download it http://fullcalendar.io/download/ ;)

Comment: thanks! in this plugin is option to add event directly from calendar (front)?

Comment: Yes, Of course, the example in the web site is readonly, but you can absolutely add events by double clicking on the calendar. You can even override the double click event to do some front-to-back logic (If you would like to add your events into a database) by posting your event parameters to a server side web service.

Comment: FullCalendar does not support recuuring events as built-in functionality, you can do a hack on this in your server side. For example, you can bind the double click event to a window which has a repeat check-box, and then, in your service-side web service, you can add all the related events in your database, so they will be automatically added into your calendar.